# Can't query value from newly created column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I just added a new column to the database for a project. I confirmed that the column exists the database. I've added the property to my model and my dbset is defined using that model. However, as soon as I try to query that column value, it gives me `NotSupportedException`.

> The specified type member 'screen_icon' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Context class

```
public partial class dml_entities : DbContext
{
    public dml_entities() : base("name=dml_entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    // ...

    public virtual DbSet<screen> screen { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Model

```
public partial class screen
{
    // ...
    public string screen_icon { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Controller code

```
public class ScreenController : ApiController
{
    private dml_entities db = new dml_entities()

    public IQueryable<object> Get_screen()
    {
        return db.screen.Select(e => new { icon = e.screen_icon });
    }
}
```

Edit:

When I `db.screen.ToList()` before selecting from it, the error goes away, but 'screen_icon' is always null, even if there actually is a value in the db.

For whatever reason, it seems like my code doesn't believe that the column exists in the database.

Edit2:

Not sure if its relevant, but the exception does not seem to trigger in the controller code itself.  Attempting to `try{} catch{}` creates the same result.

Comment: `screen_icon` should be a property, not a member variable.

Comment: Screen_icon should indeed be a property with the appropriate get, set. Also it never hurts to explicitly define the columnname with the [ColumnName("")] attribute. (note: use generics instead of object => IQueryable<T> instead of IQueryable<object>, object is going to be nasty because of casts and boxing/unboxing sooner or later)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I was retyping the declaration.  The member does have `{ get; set; }` on it.  I've edited my answer to correct this.

The `iQueryable<object>` is some grossness put in there by other developers, and I don't know own that section of the code.  I'm just an interloper trying to add a single property to the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the project was using an [edmx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc982042(v=vs.100).aspx) file to manage their models.  Due to the amount of noise in the file I edited and the fact that I found it through "go to definition" and the not the file explorer, I didn't realize that the model file was generated from the Entities.edmx file.

Once I updated the model in from the edmx designer, my code worked as expected.  And I learned that its important to keep an eye out for comments that inform you not to edit it manually because its an auto-generated file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does screen_icon has getter and setter or it is a variable? Should be a property
2. What is the name and type in database? Maybe try forcing column name with attrbiute like:

   [Column("screen_icon")]
   public string screen_icon { get; set; }

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `{ get; set; }` when I was retyping it for this question.  It is a property in the code, though.  I've updated my answer to correct that.

As to `[Column("screen_icon")]`, this doesn't appear to make a difference.  It still errors out when I try to access the property.

Comment: Try to log sql query produced by EF to check if it is valid:  
context.Database.Log = msg => Console.WriteLine(msg);

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
    return db.screen.ToList().Select(e => new { icon = e.screen_icon });
```

Comment: This does stop the error, but now the field is just always null, regardless of whether there is a value set for it in the database.

Comment: Bad "fix". You'll never get access to the database content.